# Advanced Filter: Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Either using Advanced Filter thru Excel or VBA, I am getting matches to my query string that are acting like a wildcard match. Criteria = "On Drug (GPI)" but the results include "On Drug (GPI)" & "On Drug (GPI) w/ Days Supply". How do I get an exact match?

```
Set dataRng = Range("raw_FxnTbl")
            startCol = 2
            endCol = 8
            With sumSh
                .Select
                Set pasteRng = .Range(.Cells(labelRow, startCol), .Cells(labelRow, endCol))
                dataRng.AdvancedFilter _
                    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                    CriteriaRange:=critRng, _
                    CopyToRange:=pasteRng, _
                    Unique:=True
            End With
```

critRng is defined by:

'which fxn?

```
With calcSh

    .Select

    .Cells(critRow + 1, critCol).Value = Trim(chosenItem)

    Set critRng = .Range(.Cells(critRow, critCol), .Cells(critRow + 1, critCol))

End With
```

This is the defined critRng:

critRow ==>  name

critRow+1 ==> On Drug (GPI)

Comment: It's difficult to assess without seeing how you have set the criteria range and the `critRng` variable.

Comment: See revised post

Comment: I could reproduce the issue, yes it's a weird result). See my answer below, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the criteria cell at `critRow+1`:

> old text was `On Drug (GPI)`

Enter this instead:

> `'=On Drug (GPI)`

- The apostrophe is to avoid Excel interpreting it as a formula.
- The `=` is to force Excel to make an `Exact Match` (not case sensitive though).